# CSS Menu has odd left margin

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code for a horizontal menu:

```
.vertical-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%; /******* MODIFIED ********/
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    margin-left:0;
}
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;  /******* MODIFIED ********/
}
.vertical-nav li:hover {
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a {
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li {
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu
{
    display: table;
}
.sub-menu li
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    display:table-row;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
.sub-menu li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

but it has a margin on the left that i cannot work out how to remove.

i have tried doing margin:0 and also margin:-10px etc... but it wont go.

here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QSEGR/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it isn't margin.

Web browsers apply a `padding-left` on HTML list elements such as `<ul>` *(Google Chrome set `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`)*.

You could override the user agent stylesheet by setting `padding: 0;` on `<ul>` element:

```css
.vertical-nav {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/QSEGR/2/)**

**Note:** There's also a `margin: 8px;` applied on `<body>` element by web browsers, you could reset the margin by:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

**What is the best practice?**

Different browsers may have different behavior. they apply several CSS declaration on HTML elements by default. they adds `margin`, `padding`, `text-decoration` and so on.

To get rid of this, most web developers use some CSS declarations called *CSS Reset* to override the browser's default stylesheet, as a start point.

Take a look at Legendary [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: After that there stays a small margin, he should use a document wide reset to make sure he has 100% control over the lay-out. But a good answer!

Comment: @AntonD I explained why the margin is there too ;)

Answer (score 3):

add padding: 0; to the unordered list.