# Margin browser default setting pervents me to use full screen width & height

Tags: html, css, margin

The width and height of my website is not fully used, some parts are been blanked because browser default margin.

```
.header{
     background: #493131;
     width: 100%;
     height: 10%;
}
```

And the **HTML** code contains inside the body:

```
<body>
       <div class="header"> </div>
</body>
```

The code seems to me fine though the result is this:

http://i57.tinypic.com/282j1hs.png

how to set browser default margin setting to my own setting?

Comment: I dont understand why you guys have rated my rap down..

Answer (score 2):

Just set `margin: 0;` on the `body` tag.

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: It's `margin` not `padding`.

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 in that case, can you link to your page?

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 http://jsfiddle.net/83ehq5ok/ - this works correctly with just `margin: 0;` on the body plus your code. Saying "Copy the code and run it locally" is no good to us. Show us your page

Comment: Ah OK, you saw my post in the first 10s or so before I realised I'd put padding not margin :) Glad you've got it working then

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 Just an advice, [consider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494689/css-menu-has-odd-left-margin/18494772#18494772) [reseting the default stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) at first, as a start point.

Answer (score 1):

you should reset your browser default style. it is standard reset like

```
        /**
         * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
         * http://cssreset.com
         */
        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
        a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
        del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
        small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
        b, u, i, center,
        dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, legend,
        table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
        article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
        figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
        menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
        time, mark, audio, video {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            font: inherit;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }
        /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
        article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
            display: block;
        }
        body {
            line-height: 1;
        }
        ol, ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        blockquote, q {
            quotes: none;
        }
        blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
        q:before, q:after {
            content: '';
            content: none;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Better to say `should` instead of `have to`.

Comment: Okey, i edited my answer, this was done by mistake because i am poor in English.

Answer (score 0):

```
*{ margin:0 auto; padding:0px;}
```

it will remove all default margin and padding

Comment: This will remove margin from `p` tags and stuff. It's like taking a sledgehammer to your window because it needs moving 2mm deeper into the frame.